# Multiple values for a word in Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp

I have a text file consist of words, emotion-category, and corresponded score to each emotion.

```
word    emotion emotion-intensity-score
outraged    anger   0.964
brutality   anger   0.959
devil   anger   0.953
hateful anger   0.940
terrorize   anger   0.939
tragedy sadness 0.906
anguish sadness 0.902
devil   sadness 0.900
treat   trust   0.422
travel  trust   0.422
antiseptic  trust   0.422
purr    joy 0.500
surreal joy 0.500
...
```

I've tried to retrieve the emotion-category for each input word by making a dictionary. It is possible that some words appear in more than one category but my code only retrieves one. Any solution?

```
filepath = "lexicon.txt"
f = open(filepath, 'r')
lines = f.readlines()

my_dic = {}

for line in lines:
    state_code, state_name = line.split('\t')
    my_dic[state_code.strip()] = state_name.strip()

print(my_dic['devil'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you need, I think

```
filepath = "lexicon.txt"
f = open(filepath, 'r')
lines = f.readlines()

my_dic = {}

for line in lines:
    state_code, state_name, score = line.split('\t')
    if state_code in my_dic:
        my_dic[state_code.strip()].append((state_name.strip(), float(score))
    elif state_code not in my_dic:
        my_dic[state_code.strip()] = [(state_name.strip(), float(score))]

print(my_dic['devil'])
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. But it does not get the emotion-intensity-score for each category.

Comment: Your original post didn't actually say that you needed that information, and your original code didn't seem to incorporate it. Assuming that your file is entirely tab-delimited, it should be fairly simple - edits

Comment: Check the edited code, this should encompass what you need, storing the score and its emotion as a tuple in the list.